# Vue JSX bind to class name

Tags: vue.js, jsx

I'm building a simple TodoMVC app using Vue + JSX, but the documentation seems to be seriously lacking. Thus, I'm writing down the points I need to address as part of a CR to the appropriate projects. The only document I've read as of yet is the [guide](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide), which doesn't cover much JSX at all. I don't know much about how the framework works yet, but I sure prefer using the `render` method over the string templates for performance/network reasons.

### question

What's the proper way to create a class name binding in Vue + JSX? In my `TodoItem` component, creating either a `class` or `className` attribute makes Babel throw a compile error complaining the API is deprecated (and suggesting I add several seemingly unrelated dependencies to the mix). Plus, including the `class` property in the data object seems to change nothing.

### secondary question

The lack of documentation, plus the [wording on the guide](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html#JSX) gives the impression JSX is not the "proper" way to write Vue components. Is that so? What's the idiomatic way to do it, given I don't want to ship the compiler along with my app?

### links

- [code on codepan](http://codepan.net/gist/1c61d4bfe230b62eff7cf40ff50b826f)

Comment: What's wrong with `v-bind:class`?

Comment: Babel JSX also throws:


SyntaxError: undefined: Namespaced tags/attributes are not supported. JSX is not XML.
For attributes like `xlink:href`, use `xlinkHref` instead.

Answer (score 1):

> I sure prefer using the render method over the string templates for performance/network reasons.

If you're writing `*.vue` files and bundling them with `vue-loader` (Webpack), the HTML template gets compiled into a JavaScript render function anyway, so there isn't really any kind of performance issues in that sense.

On the other hand, if you're writing your Vue components with string templates like this:

```js
new Vue({
  template: '<div>Hello</div>'
})
```

then you'll need the Vue template compiler at runtime to convert the string into a render function.

Typically people would opt for writing render functions manually if they need to do something specific that would be difficult/impossible to do with the HTML template alone.

You've probably already read the docs, but just in case, the relevant sections are:

- [Render Functions & JSX](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html#ad)
- [The Data Object In-Depth](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html#The-Data-Object-In-Depth)
- [babel-plugin-transform-vue-jsx Usage](https://github.com/vuejs/babel-plugin-transform-vue-jsx#usage)

> What's the proper way to create a class name binding in Vue + JSX?

You would just bind to the `class` attribute like you would any other attribute:

```jsx
<div class={this.klass}>
```

```js
data() {
  return {
    klass: 'foo'
  }
}
```

> The lack of documentation, plus the wording on the guide gives the impression JSX is not the "proper" way to write Vue components. Is that so? What's the idiomatic way to do it, given I don't want to ship the compiler along with my app?

JSX is definitely supported, but it is not the recommended approach. The recommended approach is to write `*.vue` files and load them with `vue-loader` (if using Webpack).

Vue comes in two versions, one with and one without the template compiler. The one with the compiler included is only for development and should not be used for production builds (unless you require string template to render function compilation at runtime, which is unlikely). See [Explanation of Build Files](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/tree/dev/dist) for more info.

Typically you write HTML string templates, and they get compiled to render functions (by `vue-loader`) *at build time*.

Comment: > You would just bind to the `class` attribute like you would any other attribute:


Like I mentioned (see linked Codepan),


> creating either a class or className attribute makes Babel throw a compile error complaining the API is deprecated


Could that be an artifact of their own setup? Or rather, an artifact of whatever Webpack setup is the "accepted" one these days?

Comment: [It works for me](http://codepan.net/gist/0715ad353fa632fb8cbe508e41bef2f4)

Comment: Interesting, looks like it works for `TodoList`, [but not `TodoItem`](http://codepan.net/gist/cd570eb68e76ac59639ca8cab8500002). I guess the problem must be something else, which increases my suspicions I may be doing something stupid...

Comment: You need to use `nativeOnClick` for native DOM elements (such as `<li>`) and `onClick` for Vue components. [Fixed](http://codepan.net/gist/05644a69d573181f914fab127d73ec0b)

Comment: That confirms my suspicions, I was indeed doing something silly. Thank you very much!

Comment: Wait a second, it looks like with `nativeOnClick` the callback doesn't really get called (no output on the console), am I crazy?

Comment: My comment about `nativeOnClick` is incorrect, sorry. Your original code should with with `onClick`. I can confirm it works in my Webpack setup but not on codepan; since I don't know their babel/webpack/vue configuration, I can only say it might be an issue on their end. I'm using babel 6, it seems codepan is using babel 7 beta.